# jquery filter using class not working

Tags: jquery

I am adding disabled property to all input element having class

```
.vehicleIsInInvoice
```

like

```
$(".vehicleIsInInvoice :input").prop("disabled", true);
```

it works correct. 
now i have to exclude input element under class

```
.excludeFromDisabled
```

for that i am using jquery filter like

```
$(".vehicleIsInInvoice :input").filter('.excludeFromDisabled').prop("disabled", true);
```

but that didn't work for me.
In short my class strchture like

```
.vehicleIsInInvoice -> .excludeFromDisabled -> input elements
```

Html of page is like

```
<div class="vehicleIsInInvoice">
    <div class="details">
        <input type="text">
    </div>  
    <div class="excludeFromDisabled">
         <input type="text">
         <input type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Mohammad how? `hasClass` just returns a boolean

Comment: In order to get the best answer you will need to include an example of the HTML markup you want to target

Answer (score 0):

The [`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) method filter input element not its parent, instead update the selector.

```
$(".vehicleIsInInvoice.excludeFromDisabled :input").prop("disabled", true);
```

---

Or with [`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) method

```
$('.vehicleIsInInvoice').filter('.excludeFromDisabled').find(':input').prop("disabled", true);
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but i think op need to prevent disabled element with class "excludeFromDisabled"

Comment: okay, nevermind then. (you wrote `':input"` instead of `':input'` or `":input"`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply select `.excludeFromDisabled` at first rather than filering it later:

```
$(".vehicleIsInInvoice:not(.excludeFromDisabled) :input").attr("disabled", true);
```

Comment: I don't want to add disabled to input element under <span class ="excludeFromDisabled">

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no HTML source I try to figure out a solution and a context:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".vehicleIsInInvoice :input").filter(function(e) {
    return $(this).closest('.excludeFromDisabled').length == 1;
  }).prop("disabled", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>

<form>
    <div class="vehicleIsInInvoice">
        <input value="vehicleIsInInvoice 1">
        <input value="vehicleIsInInvoice 2">
        <div class="excludeFromDisabled">
            <input value="excludeFromDisabled 1">
            <input value="excludeFromDisabled 2">
        </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: <div class="vehicleIsInInvoice">
    <div class="details">
        <input type="text">
    </div>  
    <div class="excludeFromDisabled">
         <input type="text">
         <input type="text">
    </div>
</div>

Comment: only thing i need to change here is                                                        return !$(this).closest('.excludeFromDisabled').length == 1;

Comment: @Raj It's a pleasure that my snippet gave you some idea. Let me know if you need other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean (only input fields, some with specific class):

```js
$(".vehicleIsInInvoice")
  .filter(function(){
    return $(this).hasClass('excludeFromDisabled');
  })
  .css('background','yellow');
```

```css
div{width:100px;padding:5px;text-align:center;border:1px solid #ccc;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="vehicleIsInInvoice" /><br>
<input type="text" class="vehicleIsInInvoice" /><br>
<input type="text" class="vehicleIsInInvoice excludeFromDisabled" /><br>
<input type="text" class="vehicleIsInInvoice" /><br>
<input type="text" class="vehicleIsInInvoice excludeFromDisabled" /><br>
<input type="text" class="vehicleIsInInvoice" /><br>
<input type="text" class="vehicleIsInInvoice" /><br>
<input type="text" class="vehicleIsInInvoice excludeFromDisabled" /><br>
<input type="text" class="vehicleIsInInvoice" /><br>
```

Or, did you mean (input fields within DIVs, some DIVs having specific class):

```js
$(".vehicleIsInInvoice")
  .filter(function(){
    return $(this).hasClass('excludeFromDisabled');
  })
  .find('input').css('background','yellow');
```

```css
div{width:180px;padding:5px;text-align:center;border:1px solid #ccc;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="vehicleIsInInvoice"><input type="text" /></div>
<div class="vehicleIsInInvoice"><input type="text" /></div>
<div class="vehicleIsInInvoice excludeFromDisabled"><input type="text" /></div>
<div class="vehicleIsInInvoice"><input type="text" /></div>
<div class="vehicleIsInInvoice excludeFromDisabled"><input type="text" /></div>
<div class="vehicleIsInInvoice excludeFromDisabled"><input type="text" /></div>
<div class="vehicleIsInInvoice"><input type="text" /></div>
<div class="vehicleIsInInvoice"><input type="text" /></div>
```

***Or,*** did you mean (input fields within DIVs, some inputs having specific class):

```js
$(".vehicleIsInInvoice")
  .filter(function(){
    return $(this).find('input').hasClass('excludeFromDisabled');
  })
  .find('input').css('background','yellow');
```

```css
div{width:180px;padding:5px;text-align:center;border:1px solid #ccc;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="vehicleIsInInvoice"><input type="text" /></div>
<div class="vehicleIsInInvoice"><input type="text" class=" excludeFromDisabled" /></div>
<div class="vehicleIsInInvoice"><input type="text" class=" excludeFromDisabled" /></div>
<div class="vehicleIsInInvoice"><input type="text" /></div>
<div class="vehicleIsInInvoice"><input type="text" class=" excludeFromDisabled" /></div>
<div class="vehicleIsInInvoice"><input type="text" /></div>
<div class="vehicleIsInInvoice"><input type="text" class=" excludeFromDisabled" /></div>
<div class="vehicleIsInInvoice"><input type="text" /></div>
```